# How I can edit followUp message (discord.py)?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have this code, however I don't understand how it is possible to edit the followup message. Thanks!

```
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    view=View()
    button_create = Button(label="CREATE", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    view.add_item(button_create)
    await ctx.send(view=view)
    async def button_callback(interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await asyncio.sleep(delay=1)
        await interaction.followup.send("Hi", ephemeral=True) # How can i edit this message? -_-

    button_create.callback = button_callback
```

I tried to use "interaction.followup.edit_message("Something")", but i got error:

> discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
> In message_id: Value "Something" is not snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

As @stijndcl said, you can use the returned [WebhookMessage](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.WebhookMessage) to [edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.WebhookMessage.edit) it.
For example:

```py
msg = await interaction.followup.send(content="Hello", wait=True)

await asyncio.sleep(5) # Wait a few seconds

await msg.edit(content="Goodbye)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in functions for it:

```
asd:discord.Message = await interaction.followup.send("Hi!")
await interaction.followup.edit_message(message_id=asd.id,content="Not Hello!")
```

This is just a basic edit. It requires a message id and a content.

Answer (score 0):

[`followup.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Webhook.send) returns the [`WebhookMessage`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.WebhookMessage) object that it sent **if you set the `wait` kwarg to `True`**, so you can store it in a variable and call [`.edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.WebhookMessage.edit) on it.

From the `send` docs:

> wait (bool) – Whether the server should wait before sending a response. This essentially means that **the return type of this function changes from None to a `WebhookMessage` if set to `True`**.

Comment: `1. await interaction.followup.send("Hi!", ephemeral=True, wait=True)

2. await interaction.followup.edit_message("Hello!")`

I tried to change, but apparently I did not fully understand how it work

Comment: I'm not gonna do it for you, no. I said you can use the `edit` method of the `WebhookMessage` that `send` returns. You're using `followup.edit_message()`, which is not at all what I said. `send` returns something, that thing has an `edit()` method that you can use. I never said anything about `followup.edit_message()`.